# NullPointerException in BufferedWriter

Tags: android

The following method shows NullPointerException.  I can't understand what is wrong with below code.  Where the file stored in

```
public class Mtx extends Activity  {
public void ConfWrite() {
    try {
     BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(getFilesDir()+"\\file.java"));

        buf.write("Hello Android");
        buf.newLine();
        buf.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

stack trace output

```
02-10 13:11:18.365: WARN/System.err(7179): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-10 13:11:18.396: WARN/System.err(7179):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getFilesDir(ContextWrapper.java:178)
02-10 13:11:18.419: WARN/System.err(7179):     at mediatronix.HAT.Mtx.ConfWrite(Mtx.java:19)
02-10 13:11:18.425: WARN/System.err(7179):     at mediatronix.HAT.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:46)
02-10 13:11:18.437: WARN/System.err(7179):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-10 13:11:18.485: WARN/System.err(7179):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
02-10 13:11:18.495: WARN/System.err(7179):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
02-10 13:11:18.505: WARN/System.err(7179):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-10 13:11:18.525: WARN/System.err(7179):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-10 13:11:18.545: WARN/System.err(7179):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-10 13:11:18.555: WARN/System.err(7179):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-10 13:11:18.585: WARN/System.err(7179):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-10 13:11:18.616: WARN/System.err(7179):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-10 13:11:18.625: WARN/System.err(7179):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-10 13:11:18.665: WARN/System.err(7179):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-10 13:11:18.675: WARN/System.err(7179):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-10 13:11:18.695: WARN/System.err(7179):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

thanks

Comment: is method getFilesDir() working properly

Comment: Post the stacktrace and the content of the getFilesDir() method (which is most likely the root of the problem).

Comment: Again, post the content of the stack trace please. And the implementation details of getFilesDir() as well.

Comment: i am newbie in android, how getFilesDir()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
getFilesDir()+"file.java"
```

try this:

```
new File(getFilesDir(), "file.java")
```

Or better yet,

```
new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
    openFileOutput("file.java", MODE_PRIVATE)))
```

Comment: @techcent - By any chance, is this being executed before `Mtx.onCreate` is called by the framework? It looks from the stack trace like `MainMenu.onCreate` is calling `Mtx.ConfWrite` before the activity actually gets off the ground. This would cause the NPE in `ContextWrapper.getFilesDir()`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
getFilesDir() + File.separator + "\file.java"
```

Edit: Thanks Heiko

Comment: You should for portability use File.separator -- \ is Windows-specific

Comment: stacktrace as in the exception that was printed (NullPointerException)